# MVC3 Deployed in IIS 7.5 - Keep getting CS1009: Unrecognised escape sequence error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I keep getting

```
Line 43:         public override void Execute() {
Line 44: WriteLiteral("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" +
Line 45: "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
Line 46: 

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ef576117\c80eec5d\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.hua2yaob.0.cs    Line: 44
```

Error message.

Can someone please help? I've done all the following items below:

If IIS was installed after .NET 4.0 on the server you need to run aspnet_regiis.exe to register it with IIS
The application pool is set to run in integrated mode
In your web.config you have the  set
You are accessing your site with http://server/home/index (change the controller and action names to match yours).
You have a route that will match the {controller}/{action} url in your Global.asax.
The corresponding view exists in ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml.

This website with same binaries runs in local machine but not on another server. The other server has MVC3 installed too

Comment: You need to post code from the view. That is what its complaining about.

Comment: I agree.  More details are needed.

Comment: Interesting how you say in your question that you have "the same binaries", yet your answer confirms that was not true. A question can only get good answers when you *accurately* report the facts. -1 for not doing so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The binaries were missing when I deployed website to another server. It was not that the code was incomplete or contained odd number of "/".  Recompiling and publishing recompiled DLLS worked.

Comment: Your answer verifies that you misreported in your question that you had properly deployed the app binaries. You can't get good answers without an accurate question