# A very weird error and the code in view in mvc has converted to a weird format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

A very weird error and the code in view in mvc has converted to a weird format

This view has lost all the code that was written in it and converted to a very strange format:
[image: This view has lost all the code that was written in it and converted to a very strange format]

and this server error displays:
[image: and this server error displays]

Please Advice how to solve this ..

Comment: Do all .cshtml files are having this issue or only one .cshtml file?

Comment: most of them are ok .. i only found this by chance when i begin to work in it .. i want to know how to know which other files are corrupted like this .. but most of the files are ok but i can't go into all views to be sure how many are corrupted

Comment: can you open the file that appears to be corrupted in notepad and see what it looks like there?

Comment: in notepad it seems to be empty but it is not it has got a lot of spaces

Comment: I never ran into it, I cannot even imagine somehow Visual Studio corrupted it. Wondering if you somehow mistakenly pasted that. Don't you have the file in your source control? Why not get it from there?

Comment: In my case, I found the same file in 'Temp' folder with different extension(.ccu). I found almost all the code except last unsaved lines.
- Try to find in windows explorer with file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any readable & valid CSHTML file should have first byte order `EF BB BF` when viewed in hex editor (if you see next `0x40H` it belongs to Razor's `@` symbol), hence possible things below may occurred in your issue:

1. The CSHTML file had overwritten with another data
2. The CSHTML file belongs to corrupted/broken part of your file system or disk
3. You have broken/malfunctioned Visual Studio installation

Since the error can't easily reproduced, it seems that you need to run data recovery tools attempting to get back original file content, then rebuild & re-deploy the solution (including recompiled DLL).

Other than that, check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/806984/recover-a-file-filled-with-zeroes-nuls-after-power-loss) SU post if you want to repair damaged file instead of restoring from backup.

Related problems:

[Compiler Error Message: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649002/compiler-error-message-cs1009-unrecognized-escape-sequence)

[MVC3 Deployed in IIS 7.5 - Keep getting CS1009: Unrecognised escape sequence error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133053/mvc3-deployed-in-iis-7-5-keep-getting-cs1009-unrecognised-escape-sequence-err)

Comment: please  tell me the data recovery tools names – i am totally lost :(